# How to save progress from a page when it refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Problem : I tried to find how to save a progress like if you are changing themes on website like you are changing the themes into dark mode, my problem is when it refresh it save/doesn't changed to the default settings.

I Already tried to have a search in youtube and i doesn't have a clue how to do it

Comment: The CSS-Tricks article [A Complete Guide to Dark Mode on the Web](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-dark-mode-on-the-web/) has a section about [Storing a User’s Preference](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-dark-mode-on-the-web/#storing-preferences)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the user's preference in the `local storage` of the browser as follows:

P.S: Try these codes on codepen

```js
const themeToggle = document.getElementById('theme-toggle');
const body = document.body;

themeToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Toggle the theme class on the body element
  body.classList.toggle('dark');

  // Save the user's preference in localStorage
  body.classList.contains('dark')?
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark'):
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
});

// Check the user's preference from localStorage on page load
const savedTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');

savedTheme === 'dark'?
  body.classList.add('dark'):
  body.classList.remove('dark')
```

```css
/* Light Theme */
body.light {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}

/* Dark Theme */
body.dark {
  background-color: #222222;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<button id="theme-toggle">Toggle Theme</button>
```

Comment: it doesn't work in vscode but it works perfectly in codepen,, can u show me how to do it in vscode? or is it supposed in codepen? because it use localstorage? can u tell me? im beginner at webdev and it was very helpfull if u can tell me every function of these javasccript code &hearts;

Comment: Are you sure you included the CSS and JS files in the HTML file?
Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: there was no error in the console

Comment: but lemme try again

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: i tried to use XAMPP but it doesn't work